# Unity How to play a particle system effect if when the parent get's disabled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, effects

How to play a particle system effect if when the parent get's disabled?

I want to play a particle system effect in the position of my obstacle. The problem is that my particle if the child of my object and when i disable the parent(object) the particle system get's disabled with it and does'nt play the affect

How can i play the effect in the same position of the obstacle and when the obstacle get's disabled/ Destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create GameObject called **ParticlesHolder**. Attach the script below to it then make sure to change the size from the Editor to `2`. Put the two Particles to each slot. The idea is that the particle won't be `disabled`.

```
public class ParticleHolder : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ParticleSystem[] effects;

    public void playParticle(int particleNumber, Vector3 particlePos)
    {
        if (effects != null && effects[particleNumber] != null)
        {
            if (effects[particleNumber].isPlaying)
                effects[particleNumber].Stop();

            ParticleSystem tempPart = Instantiate(effects[particleNumber], particlePos, new Quaternion()) as ParticleSystem;
            tempPart.Play();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, add the code below to the code in your `Example` script:

```
ParticlesContainer particle;
```

In your `Start()` function:

```
particle = GameObject.Find("ParticlesHolder").GetComponent<ParticlesContainer>();
```

In your `OnCollisionEnter()` function:

```
particle.playParticle(0, transform.position);
```

In this example, the first particle in the array would play.

If there are two particles, `0` and `1` are both valid values to pass in. If there are `3` particles then `0`,`1`,`2` are the three values to pass in.

Just like you have `public void SetDamage(int a_damage)` function, you can add `public void SetParticle(int particleId)` function to set which particle to play.

Comment: i want a normal particle to play on a normal object and a explosion particle that plays on a special object

Comment: @Groude I know your problem. Did you read the answer? Did you do that?

Comment: Yes and nothing happens

Comment: @Groude You assigned both particles to the `effects` slot in `ParticlesContainer`  script? Put **PUT** edit in your question then update your question with your latest `Example` script. I want to see.

Comment: Nice. Ok let's make sure that your particle is even playing. Put `particle.playParticle(0, transform.position);` to your `Start()` function after `particle = GameObject.Find("ParticlesHolder").GetComponent<ParticleHolder>();` If it doesn't play then there is something wrong. Let me know if it does or not.

Comment: Nothing happens. Do i need to have the particle in the hierarchy though? cuz i got it only as prefab

Comment: @Groude It looks like. I didn't know you had it as a prefab. Before you do that, replace `effects[particleNumber].Play();`  **in**  `ParticlesContainer` script **with** `particle.enableEmission = true;` and let me know if that works.

Comment: there is no enableEmission ... idk  Error CS1061: Type `ParticleHolder' does not contain a definition for `enableEmission' and no extension method `enableEmission' of type `ParticleHolder' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116629/discussion-between-programmer-and-groude).

Comment: This is awesome fix

Comment: hey again, can u help me with something?